# How to implement synchronisization when log write by 100 applications at a time in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, locking

```
public class Logwriter {
    public Void WriteXml()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Log_Data.xml");

        XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("entry");
        XmlElement xmldata = xmlDoc.CreateElement("data");
                    XmlElement xmlcontent = xmlDoc.CreateElement("content");

                    xmldata.InnerText ="1234" ;
        xmlcontent.InnerText ="Stackoverflow";

                    newelement.AppendChild(xmldata);
        newelement.AppendChild(xmlcontent);

                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
        xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Log_Data.xml");
}}
```

Above WriteXml() function can be called by 100 applications at a time so i have to prevent IOException Error.
I can avod these exception using lock so how can i do it.
please explain which object i have to lock during writing xml

Comment: Are these 100 applications separate processes? or do you mean things (threads/callbacks/tasks/whatever) inside the same process?

Comment: 100 different processes, do you mean? If so, `lock` isn't going to help you, as that's only within a single process. If you've got 100 different processes, why don't you get each one to write to its own file? Note that this sort of logging (where adding a single entry involves reading *everything* logged so far) is very inefficient.

Comment: ya means 100 diffrent aplication that can be windows service,web app,windows form,web service etc

Comment: @lax it would be very odd for a winform (traditionally a desktop app) and a web-app/web-service (traditionally a server app) to co-exist...

Comment: above function which is in class Logwriter class so i can implement this class in all my apps...

Comment: A plain text file would be better than an XML file. Then you can just append to the end and that is a much faster operation. (Not that this answers the question with regard to serializing writes.)

Comment: If the purpose is logging and if there is not special need to write your own logging functionality, Can you not use time-tested framework like Log4Net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about a named mutex; you can use a `Mutex` with a name like `Global\MySharedLog`, which will then be visible to different applications in different sessions on the same machine. This allows each exe to take an exclusive lock (in a managed way) for a period of time.

However!

- having a separate log per application would be a lot simpler and more efficient
- xml is not a great log format, especially if you are going to read/write the entire thing every time to add a row; sounds fine on log-entry #10, not so fine on  log-entry #12,301,023

For example:

```
Mutex m = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MySharedLog");
...

m.WaitOne();
try {
    // do some work here
} finally {
    m.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: how i implement my method using mutex

Comment: @lax like in the example above... just substitute your code that requires synchronized access for the "do some work here".

Comment: Marc means i have write whole writeXml functon there

Comment: @lax I'm confused what the issue is.... not sure whether "fisible" means "fixable" or "feasible", but: there is nothing to fix, and it is entirely feasible

Comment: fisible means stable no exception during log writing...except my xml code write function

Comment: @lax indeed; if you put your log-writing in the "do some work here", and use that pattern in every caller, then the apps won't be fighting over the file at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you require a separate Windows Service that can receive log messages via TCP packets sent from your 100 applications. This would effectively serialize the file access.

Your logging routine would then have to POST data to `localhost` on a specific port.

The Windows Service would buffer and then write the log entries to the file in its own time.